# Why didn't Brice suggest this?

Tags: plot-explanation, no-way-out

In the 1987 film No Way Out, Secretary of Defense David Brice is out to quash a proposed "phantom submarine", a naval craft that in theory wouldn't be detected by sonar. His main problem seems to be the designers are pushing for a sub that's "roughly the size of an aircraft carrier- the Russians won't need sonar to find it, they'll just see this huge bulge out in the ocean".

Instead of squashing the project outright, couldn't Brice have suggested a smaller craft?

Comment: Suggesting alternatives isn't his job. His job is to evaluate the project put in front of him.